# Call function from other file - identifier not found on Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have class named HealthComponent and GamemodeBase with .cpp and .h files. In GamemodeBase header file i had declared void funtion HealthBar(float fHealth). I want to call it in HealtComponent implementation file but i getting indentifier not found error. I include GamemodeBase.h so IMO this should work.

```
GameModeBase.h

public:
UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent)
        void HealthBar(float nHealth);

HealthComponent.cpp

#include "Game/MyGameModeBase.h"
...
if(PlayerGetDamage())
    HealthBar(fHealth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the GameMode in order to call non static functions on it.

If the HealthComponent is attached to the GameMode, you can simply cast the owner of the HealthComponent to the GameMode.

```
AMyGameModeBase* GameMode = Cast<AMyGameModeBase>(GetOwner());
GameMode->HealthBar(fHealth);
```

Alternatively you can access the GameMode via the World.

```
AMyGameModeBase* GameMode = GetWorld()->GetAuthGameMode<AMyGameModeBase>();
GameMode->HealthBar(fHealth);
```

I recommend the second approach as its more generic.

Also please keep in mind for Multiplayer, the GameMode does not exist on Clients. The GameMode only ever exists on the Server.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make HealthBar a static function and call it with GameModeBase::HealthBar() or make an object of GameModeBase in HealthComponent and call it with object.HealthBar()

Comment: Can you paste ur current code in comment after my advice?